# Start programs in the background and kill them as soon as one of them dies with an exit code

Tags: python, bash, shell, subprocess, kill

On Linux, I would like to spawn off some servers as background services.

**As soon as one of them terminates with an exit code != 0**, they shall **all** to be SIGTERMed, and after 3 seconds grace period be KILLed if they don't want to go.

The same shall happen when Ctrl-C is pressed.

I want a rough equivalent of

```
set -e
server1 &
server2 &
server3 &
wait (+ kill on error)
```

(Unfortunately that code above does **not** have all the mentioned properties.)

It shall **not** be possible for children to steal/escape the Ctrl-C signals.

I accept solutions in **Bash** and **Python** (using `subprocess`). For Python they may only use standard library functions (nothing I have to download modules with `pip` first). If you have a cool way to do this in another language, please do not hesitate to show it.

Bonus points if it also works on Mac OS.

Comment: What will my bonus points consist of? Is it money?

Comment: @jldupont Why not add supervisor as an answer so we can discuss it?

Comment: @nh2: because it doesn't directly within the parameters you have set i.e. no additional modules).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than write the solution for you, I will suggest where to look:  `setpgrp`, `waitpid`, `kill`.  Note that "It shall not be possible for children to steal/escape the Ctrl-C signals." is neither possible (the only signals that cannot be evaded are `SIGSTOP` and `SIGKILL`) nor meaningful (you aren't delivering `SIGINT` to them).

You can't do this properly in `bash` because `wait` waits for all specified (or, if none are specified, simply all) processes; you need "any" semantics, not "all".

Answer (score 0):

It *is* technically possible to do this directly in bash, but I wouldn't, because it requires a lot of polling and will be inefficient and error-prone (basically you have to `kill -0 $pid` to test if the process is still around).  Here's a bit of bash code (from a script I have lying around) that shows how to record a backgrounded process pid:

```
start_tail() {
    if [ x$TAIL_PID != x ]; then
        echo "internal error: already running tail (pid $TAIL_PID)"
    fi
    tail -0f $1 &
    TAIL_PID=$!
    trap "kill $TAIL_PID" 0 1 2 3 15
}

stop_tail() {
    if [ x$TAIL_PID != x ]; then
        kill $TAIL_PID; trap 0 1 2 3 15
        TAIL_PID=""
    fi
}
```

and in this particular case you could probably make it work better (than the above, which is deliberately limited) using a "coprocess" and a fair bit of hacking.

It will be easier in Python, but don't use `subprocess`; use direct OS calls (as @geekosaur described above).  @jldupont's recommendation for http://supervisord.org/ looks like a good one (especially since it is written in Python).

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
# Avoid <() process substitutions for portability's sake
set -bm
trap clean SIGCHLD
trap 'kill 0' SIGINT
trap 'sleep 3; kill -9 0' SIGTERM

clean() {
        while read spec pid extra; do
                wait $pid || kill 0
        done << EOF
                $( jobs -l | grep 'Exit\|Done' )
EOF
}

server1 &
server2 &
server3 &
wait
```